# Смещение текста

Tags: css

Добрый день)
Есть css класс:

```
.sbc {
  background: url(../images/block_02.gif) repeat-x left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

padding-top смещает как текст, так и бэкграунд вниз. Как сделать так, чтобы вниз смещался только текст. Спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background-position: 0 -11px;
```

Но в вашем случае луше пользоваться увеличением line-height: заодно само отцентрируется.

Comment: line-height реально помог) спасибо)) вот с background-position придется помудрить

Comment: Галочка слева ;)